# Comparing C macro with text value

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible in C to compare a macro with a text value, like this:

```
#if MACRO == val
    code;
#endif
```

I have attempted doing this but it hasn't worked so far. Is this at all possible, and  if not, what is a good alternative?

Comment: It's possible if `MACRO` and `val` are integers.  Not strings, though.

Comment: No, the preprocessor can only do integer arithmetic.

Comment: You can do `#define RED 1` and `#define GREEN 2` and `#define BLUE 3`, and then do something like `#define color RED`, and finally do things like `#if color == BLUE`.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought

Comment: @SteveSummit: Re “It's possible if `MACRO` and `val` are integers”: So if `val` is an integer, as in `int val;`, that means it is possible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you say so. :-) (But I take your point.)